# How to compile OpenCL C++ in QT Creator

Tags: qt, cmake, opencl

Just trying to share:
I was trying to compile a simple C++ program in QT using OpenCL.
this line:

```
#include "CL/cl.hpp"
```

was giving me the following errors:

> error "SSE2 instruction set not enabled"
>
> error "SSE2 instruction set not enabled"
>
> '_mm_mfence' was not declared in this scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve I had to set the compile flags:

```
-msse -msse2
```

to do that in QT, if you are using CMakeLists.txt,
you need to add the line:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-msse -msse2")
```

some other important lines in the same file.

```
find_package(OpenCL REQUIRED)
set( ADDITIONAL_LIBS -lOpenCL)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
${OPENCL_LIBRARIES}
)
```

Hope this helps someone save some time.